# Two ways to implement a callback, so what is he difference

Tags: java, android

I have a class which has a method called `connect(par1, par2, par3)`, `par3` is an `interface/listenr`.

To provide `par3` i can do as follows:

```
connect(par1, par2, asynchCallBack2 );
private class asynchCallBack2 implements MqttCallback {
...
...
}
```

OR:

```
 connect(par1, par2, asynchCallBack2 );
 MqttCallback  asynchCallBack2 = new MqttCallback  {
 ...
 ...
 }
```

And in either cases, every thing works jus fine. So what is the difference and in which scenarios each of the implementation is used?

Comment: see this http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

Answer (score 1):

In one case (i.e. where you say implements) you are defining full fledge method local class.

While for the other you are defining anonymous class which is similar to the one where you said implements. Just that you aren't defining the name and say like implements myinterface which is implicit to compiler.

It's just the way you define your class, nothing changes in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is **requirement** and handling **exceptional** cases ,Hope this pseudo code clears it for you

```
   interface Engine{
    public void start();
}

private class FerrariEngine implements Engine{
    public void preStartRoutine(){}
    public void Start(){}
}

private class Main{

    private void main(){
        Engine engine=getEngine();
        if(engine instanceOf FerrariEngine){
            ((FerrariEngine)engine).preStartRoutine();
        }
        engine.start();
    }

    private Engine getEngine(){


        if(System==Generic)
        return new Engine{
            @override
            public void start(){
                //Do start
            }
        }
        else if(System==Ferrari)
        return new FerrariEngine();

    }
}
```

As a general principle,If u need more functionality whilst still being able to adhere to older version, creating an instance of an extended version of  that class instead of making an anonymous instance makes sense.